# Why is my Python exec script from a Java file returning an empty InputStream?

Tags: java, python, exec

I am trying to exec a python script using a Java Process. I have a file called test.py that has a print("Hello world") statement on line 1.

My Java code is the following:

```
String command = "python test.py";
Process py_process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader input_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(py_process.getInputStream()));
String line = input_reader.readLine();
input_reader.close();
System.out.println(line);
```

My code compiles with no errors and prints null as the line value from the input stream, should it not say hello world? I see many other questions about this, but none that get null as the return value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try adding a `waitFor()` after `exec(command)`. It is most probably because the input is ready before the python script prints.

Comment: What do you mean after exec @plumSemPy? On a new line or what?

Comment: sorry for being unclear, I meant `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor();`

Comment: @plumSemPy waitFor() returns an int

Comment: oh i did not realize you are using the py_process later, how about
```
Process py_process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
py_process.waitFor();
.
.
.
```